# Rotating Sprite around inner and outer points Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, rotation, sprite

How can I rotate Sprite around inner and outer points in the same time?

If I do like that:

```
        sprite.setOrigin(innerX, InnerY);
        sprite.rotate(angle1);
        sprite.setOrigin(outerX, outerY);
        sprite.rotate(angle2);
```

libgdx rotates sprite on angle1 + angle2 arount outer point. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I don't have enough reputation for commenting)
Can you provide some more information? It is hard to make out the mistake.

Possible solutions as of now could be:

- Are the inner values really the one you expect? Have you logged them and checked if they are different?
- `InnerY`starts with a capital 'I', is this correct?

**EDIT:**

So I tried to recreate your problem and it is working fine for me. Maybe my example can help you:

```
    sprite = new Sprite(textureAtlas.findRegion("circle14"));
    sprite.setBounds(0, 0 , sprite.getRegionWidth(), sprite.getRegionHeight());

    // This is used to calculate an example innerX and innerY
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/3f, sprite.getHeight()/3f);
    sprite.rotate(30f);

    // This is used to calculate an example outerX and outerY
    sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() * 1.5f, sprite.getHeight()*1.5f);
    sprite.rotate(30f);
```

Don't forget to draw your sprite in your render method like this:

```
sprite.draw(batch);
```

Comment: For example I have rectangle 50x30 and I want to rotate it in (20,10) position - inner point, and then to rotate it in (70,50) position - outer, and all it in the same time, it`s like rotating wheel on another rotating invisible wheel, I hope you understand :)

Comment: inner values are really the one I expect, capital 'I' - just mistake in example, sorry, in code it`s okay